# Jetpack Compose - Search bar won't allow me to search and the cursor will not show up

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I have a custom search bar will not allow me to place a cursor and type text into it. Before adding the viewmodel and state, I was able to have the TextField work and allow typing text into it.

I've tried using state variables within the composable instead of separating the logic into the view model and unfortunatly recieved the same result. I have a feeling it's something simple that I'm missing but can't quite find it.

Custom Search Bar:

```
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    modifier: Modifier,
    viewModel: ToolSetListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){

    Surface (
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(74.dp)
            .padding(20.dp, 15.dp, 20.dp, 0.dp),
        elevation = 10.dp,
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(25)
            ){

        TextField(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = viewModel.searchText,
            onValueChange = {
                viewModel.onEvent(ToolSetListEvent.OnSearchToolSet(it))
            },
            placeholder = {
                Text(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .alpha(ContentAlpha.medium),
                    text = "Search...",
                    color = White
                )
            },
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1.fontSize,
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                cursorColor = White
            )
        )

    }
```

Screen:

```
@Composable
fun ToolSetListScreen(
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit,
    viewModel: ToolSetListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val toolSets = viewModel.toolSets.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collect { event ->
            when(event) {
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> onNavigate(event)
            }
        }
    }
    Scaffold (
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                viewModel.onEvent(ToolSetListEvent.OnAddToolSetClick)
            }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Add")
            }
        }
            ) {
        SearchBar(
            modifier = Modifier,
            )
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                .padding(0.dp, 20.dp)
        ) {
            items(toolSets.value) { toolset ->
                ToolSetItem(
                    toolSet = toolset,
                    onEvent = viewModel::onEvent,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            viewModel.onEvent(ToolSetListEvent.OnToolSetClick(toolset))
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ToolSetListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ToolSetRepository
): ViewModel() {

    val toolSets = repository.getAllToolSets()
    private val _uiEvent =  Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    var searchText by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    fun onEvent(event: ToolSetListEvent) {
        when(event) {
            is ToolSetListEvent.OnToolSetClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(Routes.ADD_EDIT_TOOL_SET + "?PONumber=${event.toolSet.PONumber}"))
            }
            is ToolSetListEvent.OnDeleteToolSetClick -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    repository.deleteToolSet(event.toolset)
                }
            }
            is ToolSetListEvent.OnAddToolSetClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(Routes.ADD_EDIT_TOOL_SET))
            }
            is ToolSetListEvent.OnSearchToolSet -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    if (event.searchText.isNotBlank()) {
                        searchText = event.searchText
                        repository.getToolSetByPO(event.searchText)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(event: UiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiEvent.send(event)
        }
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PunchesManagerTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                Scaffold (
                    content = {
                        Navigation(navController)
                              },
                    bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController) },
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    BottomNavigation {
      val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
      val currentRoute = backStackEntry?.destination?.route


        NavBarItems.bottomNavItem.forEach { navItem ->
            BottomNavigationItem(selected = currentRoute == navItem.route, onClick = {
                navController.navigate(navItem.route) {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = false
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
            },
                icon = {
                    Icon(imageVector = navItem.icon,
                    contentDescription = navItem.name)
                },
                label = {
                    Text(text = navItem.name)
                },
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the fix!

I adjusted the layout of my scaffoled in my ToolSetListScreen:

```
 Scaffold (
        content = {
            SearchBar(
                modifier = Modifier,
            )
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(0.dp, 75.dp)
            ) {
                items(toolSets.value) { toolset ->
                    ToolSetItem(
                        toolSet = toolset,
                        onEvent = viewModel::onEvent,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(16.dp)
                            .clickable {
                                viewModel.onEvent(ToolSetListEvent.OnToolSetClick(toolset))
                            }
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                viewModel.onEvent(ToolSetListEvent.OnAddToolSetClick)
            }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Add")
            }
        }
            )
}
```

and this seemed to work.

Comment: Were you able to get the search logic to work? Because I have a similar problem and i keep getting requestCusorUpdates is not supported.